English Mishna Berurah PDF
Does anyone know where I can find a PDF or a different downloadable format of an English translation of the Mishna Berurah?
The answers offered at this similar question do not work or are incomplete.
Any help much appreciated :D

Translations of halachic works are hard and expensive. There is a very high-quality translation available (MB Ohr Olam) and it is not cheap (also because it takes many physical volumes). Not sure you will find this online for free, and I would be very cautious paskening halacha from it unless you can check for yourself in the original that the translation is correct

This is a literal duplicate, the fact there are no good answers on the other question is no reason to ask a second time. Better is to ask someone to offer a bounty on the duplicate question to encourage posters to post answers there. At the same time we all have the same search engines, if there was an easy answer it would be there already
